# External Monitor and Screen Brightness Funcitionality Lost At The Same Time

Tags: graphics, brightness, monitor

I've been using Ubuntu several years, and since yesterday, I am unable to connect to my external monitor, and it seems at the same time that my laptop's screen brightness functionality was also lost. This happened after I downloaded an update yesterday prompted by Ubuntu's Software Updater.

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E5570 and uses 64 bit Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. (Intel® Core™ i5-6440HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4; 12 GB memory; partitioned hard drive (500 GB) for Windows 10; GNOME version 42.9; Windowing System X11)

What also seems strange is that the graphics card reflected in Settings, About is:  llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits), but when I run this command in Terminal (lspci | grep VGA) it shows: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06).

Can anyone suggest solutions to these two problems ?